# Dynamic Tables using JS DOM

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to populate the table on my webpage dynamically using the DOM. My idea is to use the generateTable function, pass each table as an argument and have switch cases inside the function for each table. When I tested out the first table, nothing is displaying in the browser.

**Here is the JS:**

```
var language = "English";
    var subtitle;
    window.onload = function() {
    generateTable("list");
    subtitle = document.querySelector("#subtitle");
    document.querySelector("#menu_21").onclick = function () { generateTable('pop1');};
    document.querySelector("#menu_22").onclick = function () { generateTable('pop2');};
    document.querySelector("#menu_31").onclick = function () { generateTable('aac1');};
    document.querySelector("#menu_32").onclick = function () { generateTable('aac2');};
    document.querySelector("#menu_41").onclick = function () { generateTable('lang1');};
    document.querySelector("#menu_42").onclick = function () { generateTable('lang2');};
    document.querySelector("#menu_43").onclick = function () { generateTable('lang3');};
    document.querySelector("#menu_44").onclick = function () { generateTable('lang4');};
    document.querySelector("#menu_45").onclick = function () { generateTable('lang5');};
    document.querySelector("#menu_46").onclick = function () { generateTable('lang6');};
    document.querySelector("#menu_47").onclick = function () { generateTable('lang7');};
    document.querySelector("#menu_48").onclick = function () { generateTable('lang8');};
}

function getTdImgElement(url,alt,height,width) {
    var cell = document.createElement("td");
    var image = document.createElement("img");
    image.setAttribute("src", url);
    image.setAttribute("alt", alt);
    if (height) image.setAttribute("height", height);
    if (width) image.setAttribute("width", width);
    cell.appendChild(image);
    return cell;
}

function getRow (i) {
    var row = document.createElement("tr");
    var imageURL = "../../flags/" + countries[i].Code.toLowerCase() + ".png";
    row.appendChild(getTdImgElement(imageURL,"",20px,20px));
    for (int j = 0;j < countries[i].length - 1;j++) {
    var cell = document.createElement("td");
    cell.appendChild(document.createTextNode(countries[i][j]));
    }
    var lastCell = document.createElement("td");
    lastCell.appendChild(document.createTextNode(countries[i].Name.language));
    cell += lastCell;
    row.appendChild(cell);
    tableBody.appendChild(row);
}

function generateTable(a) {
document.querySelector('#subtitle').innerHTML = "Hello!";
    var tableBody = document.querySelector("#tableBody");
    if (a == 'pop1') {
    document.querySelector('#subtitle').innerHTML = "Hello!";
    for (int i = 0; i < countries.length;i++) {
        getRow(i);
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: At the very least you need to at pass `i` into `getRow()`

Comment: You're right,fixed

Answer (score 1):

There is a lot of syntax errors, this below should be better.

```
var language = "English";
var subtitle;
window.onload = () => {
generateTable("list");
subtitle = document.querySelector("#subtitle");
document.querySelector("#menu_21").onclick = function() {
    generateTable('pop1');
};
document.querySelector("#menu_22").onclick = function() {
    generateTable('pop2');
};
document.querySelector("#menu_31").onclick = function() {
    generateTable('aac1');
};
document.querySelector("#menu_32").onclick = function() {
    generateTable('aac2');
};
document.querySelector("#menu_41").onclick = function() {
    generateTable('lang1');
};
document.querySelector("#menu_42").onclick = function() {
    generateTable('lang2');
};
document.querySelector("#menu_43").onclick = function() {
    generateTable('lang3');
};
document.querySelector("#menu_44").onclick = function() {
    generateTable('lang4');
};
document.querySelector("#menu_45").onclick = function() {
    generateTable('lang5');
};
document.querySelector("#menu_46").onclick = function() {
    generateTable('lang6');
};
document.querySelector("#menu_47").onclick = function() {
    generateTable('lang7');
};
document.querySelector("#menu_48").onclick = function() {
    generateTable('lang8');
};
};

function getTdImgElement(url, alt, height, width) {
var cell = document.createElement("td");
var image = document.createElement("img");
image.setAttribute("src", url);
image.setAttribute("alt", alt);
if (height) image.setAttribute("height", height);
if (width) image.setAttribute("width", width);
cell.appendChild(image);
return cell;
}

function getRow() {
var row = document.createElement("tr");
var imageURL = "../../flags/" + countries[i].Code.toLowerCase() + ".png";
row.appendChild(getTdImgElement(imageURL, "", 20, 20));
for (j = 0; j < countries[i].length - 1; j++) {
    var cell = document.createElement("td");
    cell.appendChild(document.createTextNode(countries[i][j]));
}
var lastCell = document.createElement("td");
lastCell.appendChild(document.createTextNode(countries[i].Name.language));
cell += lastCell;
row.appendChild(cell);
tableBody.appendChild(row);
}

function generateTable(a) {
document.querySelector('#subtitle').innerHTML = "Hello!";
var tableBody = document.querySelector("#tableBody");
if (a == 'pop1') {
    document.querySelector('#subtitle').innerHTML = "Hello!";
    for (i = 0; i < countries.length; i++) {
    getRow();
    }
}
}
```